# C++ Winapi waveOutSetVolume()

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, waveout

I want to change the master volume with the function

```
MMRESULT waveOutSetVolume(
  HWAVEOUT hwo, 
  DWORD dwVolume 
); 

hwo
Handle to an open waveform-audio output device. This parameter can also be a device identifier.
```

How do I create a handler for the Master Volume?

```
dwVolume
Specifies a new volume setting. The low-order word contains the left-channel volume setting, and the high-order word contains the right-channel setting. A value of 0xFFFF represents full volume, and a value of 0x0000 is silence.
If a device does not support both left and right volume control, the low-order word of dwVolume specifies the volume level, and the high-order word is ignored.
```

How do I pass the Volume (for example 75) to the function?

Trying it like this : [How to change master volume programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771775/how-to-change-master-volume-programmatically) doesnt't work for me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no master volume change in Vista+ through legacy `waveOutXxx` API. Use WASAPI instead:

- [About WASAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Endpoint Volume Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370839%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> If a device has a hardware volume control, **changes made to the control
>   through the `IAudioEndpointVolume` interface** affect the volume level
>   both in shared mode and in exclusive mode. If a device lacks hardware
>   volume and mute controls, changes made to the software volume and mute
>   controls through this interface affect the volume level in shared
>   mode, but not in exclusive mode. In exclusive mode, the application
>   and the audio hardware exchange audio data directly, bypassing the
>   software controls.

Comment: Thanks, but does WASAPI include a function that just need the volume and a handler as input, like the WINAPI function?

Comment: It's not a single function. I linked relevant MSDN page to be a lead for you.