# Determine whether the Master System Volume is muted?

Tags: windows, vbscript, wmi, volume, mute

I would like to write an Script to determine whether the Master System Volume is muted, to mute it or unmute it.

Basically I want to do what is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216334/how-to-control-windows-system-volume-using-jscript-or-vbscript) answer:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys(chr(&hAD))
```

...but with a little improvement, what I would like to perform are two procedures, one for mute and the other for unmute, so I need to determine if it's muted or not.

I already know how to do this using 3rd party libraries in other languages, but I need to do it with VisualBasicScipt so I have no idea where to start in this limited language, maybe WMI tells something about the current master volume level? if yes then I suppose that could save me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.run"%SystemRoot%\System32\SndVol.exe" 'Runs The Master Volume App.
WScript.Sleep 1500 'Waits For The Program To Open
oShell.SendKeys("{PGUP}") 'Turns Up The Volume 20, If It Is Muted Then It Will Unmute It
oShell.SendKeys("{PGUP}") 'Turns Up The Volume 20
oShell.SendKeys("{PGUP}") 'Turns Up The Volume 20
oShell.SendKeys("{PGUP}") 'Turns Up The Volume 20
oShell.SendKeys("{PGUP}") 'Turns Up The Volume 20
oShell.SendKeys"%{F4}"  ' ALT F4 To Exit The App.
```

This Runs The Master Volume And Unmutes IT And Sets The Volume To 100
If You Want To Decrease The Volume Do The Following

```
oShell.SendKeys('{PGDN}')
```

Answer (score 2):

VBScript/Windows Script Host/WMI do not provide this info. You'll need to use third-party utilities or some other programming languages, e.g.:

- [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294292/113116)
- [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348221/113116)
- [Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16668504/113116)