# Get recording device volume programmatically/command line in XP

Tags: audio, windows-xp

Is there any way to get the current volume/mute value of the currently default recording device programmatically or from the command line? I did a little .exe in C++ for Vista+ that uses EndpointVolume API but unfortunately it's not available for Windows XP. Any workaround?

I don't need to change them, just get them from my application to be able to react to them.

Thanks!

Comment: In XP, a pre WASAPI OS, you need an older API for this, see [How to get the master volume in windows xp?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4505578/868014)

Comment: I'll take a look and check if I can make it work for my case. Thanks for the help!